# What are some of the most intense and beautiful adjectives that a writer can use to describe the word "laugh"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm looking for adjectives conveying energy and pure unadulterated joy, specifically modifying the noun "laugh". (Or, alternatively, "guffaw")

Comment: I think _maniacally_ sounds good.

Comment: She LOLed so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about **a rambunctious laugh** ?

> - **"uncontrolled in a way that is playful or full of energy"** - [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rambunctious)

**"She let out a rambunctious laugh"**
"I was surprised. **I didn't expect such a rambunctious laugh."**

OR

- **a boisterous laugh?**
- **a belly-laugh?**
- **a hearty laugh?**
- **an explosive laugh?**
- **a roaring laugh?**
- **or a convulsive laugh?**

Answer (score 1):

She shocked me by letting loose an unrestrained, blissful, bright, bubbly, joyous, and raucous laugh.

Answer (score 1):

Laughter is one of the few verbs you can do [uproariously](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/uproarious), so I'd use that!

Comment: A variant close to this proposal is "**a roar of laughter**".